# python flask generate csv without losing first row

Tags: python, csv, flask, generator

The following is a code snippet used to generate csv data from database rows on a flask view.

The `CSV_HEADERS` is a constant that describes the csv header row. This should be the first row to be generated/ yielded.

However the current for loop will always never yield the first database row i.e. when the count equals zero. How do generate the csv header without losing the first row.

```
@app.route('/all.csv')
def generate_all_csv():
    """
     Return all data as csv.

    """
    def generate():
        """
        CSV generator.
        """
        count = 0
        for row in database.get_all_rows():
            if count == 0:
                count = 1
                yield CSV_HEADERS
            else:
                csv_res = ','.join(row) + '\n'
                yield csv_res

return Response(generate(), mimetype='text/csv')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just yield the header **before** looping:

```
def generate():
    """
    CSV generator.
    """
    yield CSV_HEADERS

    for row in database.get_all_rows():
        csv_res = ','.join(row) + '\n'
        yield csv_res
```

The `yield` expression does not require a loop in the generator function.

If you wanted to produce the header only if there was data, track if you produced a header:

```
def generate():
    """
    CSV generator.
    """
    yielded_headers = False

    for row in database.get_all_rows():
        if not yielded_headers:
            yield CSV_HEADERS
            yielded_headers = True

        csv_res = ','.join(row) + '\n'
        yield csv_res
```

or use `enumerate()` to number your loop and yield when the index is 0:

```
def generate():
    """
    CSV generator.
    """
    for i, row in enumerate(database.get_all_rows()):
        if i == 0:
            yield CSV_HEADERS

        csv_res = ','.join(row) + '\n'
        yield csv_res
```

Comment: If you only want the header row when there's data, just remove the `else`.

Comment: @dirn: I added some options for that.